# Pandas - converting dates to datetime, day-month-year to year month day fails with parse dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of patients and operations, with 6 date columns. The dates are in the format of 
day-month-year. To get the hospital length of stay I need to subtract the admission date [ADMIDATE] from the discharge date (DISDATE). I want to change the date columns to datetime columns.

As an example

```
    ADMIDATE    DISDATE
0   06/06/2014  07/06/2014
1   23/06/2014  23/06/2014
```

if  use

```
pd.read_csv('/Users/.......csv', parse_dates=['ADMIDATE', 'DISDATE'])
```

I get

```
    ADMIDATE    DISDATE
0   2014-06-06  2014-07-06
1   2014-06-23  2014-06-23
```

and the 7th June is turned into the 6th July.(DISDATE , row[0] )
If I use the more strict

```
for col in ['ADMIDATE', 'DISDATE']:
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

it works

```
ADMIDATE    DISDATE
0   2014-06-06  2014-06-07
1   2014-06-23  2014-06-23
```

But it won't accept the many empty rows where for instance the patient hasn't yet been discharged at the time of data collection. I can format the date columns in excel to get the csv into year-month-day format and then use parse dates and it works correctly but I would like to know what I can do with `to_datetime`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `dayfirst`

This argument forces the parser to interpret the day first

```
df.apply(pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=True)

    ADMIDATE    DISDATE
0 2014-06-06 2014-06-07
1 2014-06-23 2014-06-23
```

To specify columns:

```
df[['ADMIDATE', 'DISDATE']].apply(pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=True)

    ADMIDATE    DISDATE
0 2014-06-06 2014-06-07
1 2014-06-23 2014-06-23
```

---

#### `error='coerce'`

To accommodate missing data:

```
df[['ADMIDATE', 'DISDATE']].apply(
    pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=True, errors='coerce'
)

    ADMIDATE    DISDATE
0 2014-06-06 2014-06-07
1 2014-06-23 2014-06-23
```